# Using NSPipe for interactive commands

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nspipe

I'm launching some interactive process inside my OS X app I want to be able to read and write from pipes.

For example: Launching the process will wait for user to type command. When user is finished (aka pressed enter), process will return something and then again wait for user.

For now, I'm using `NSPipe` class for communication, but the problem is when method `writeData:` is called, I have to call `closeFile` in order to get notification `NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification`.

Complete code (with changed folder paths) is this

```
dispatch_queue_t taskQueue =
   dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
  dispatch_async(taskQueue, ^{

    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setStandardOutput: [NSPipe pipe]];
    [task setStandardInput: [NSPipe pipe]];
    [task setStandardError: [task standardOutput]];
    [task setLaunchPath: @"/Users/..."];
    [task setArguments:@[@"--interaction"]];

    [[[task standardOutput] fileHandleForReading] waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
        addObserverForName:NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification
                    object:[[task standardOutput] fileHandleForReading]
                     queue:nil
                usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification){
        NSData *output = [[[task standardOutput] fileHandleForReading] availableData];
        NSString *outStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:output encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"avaliable data: %@", outStr);
            NSString * message = @"IOTCM \"/Users/.../Demo.agda\" None Indirect ( Cmd_show_version )";
            [[[task standardInput] fileHandleForWriting] 
                   writeData:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        });
        [[[task standardOutput] fileHandleForReading] waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];
    }];

    [task launch];
    [task waitUntilExit];
});
```

Note that I get first notification (process is responding), but no notification comes after `writeData:` gets called.

How to achieve communication, that:

1. gets launched (and stays launched through app lifecycle)
2. writing and reading is supported

Comment: Don't you need a newline at the end of the command?

Comment: Maybe? Will try and accept if this does the trick. And I will buy you a beer, if this works :) thanks!

Comment: If you live in Germany then I will bite your hand off for the beer ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately no, but I will come to Oktoberfest and buy you a "kriegel" of beer! That works!!! :)))) Gosh, why isn't this in the documentation? Or is this a "general knowledge"? I'm new to pipes all all this IPC voodoo stuff... Anyway, Danke shon!

Comment: Maybe you can write complete answer, so I can accept it? Maybe there is someone who is also smashing head against keyboard this moment because of this :D

Comment: OK will do.  I am actually English and just speak German beer, not the language :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append a newline to any commands you send to the pipe, in the same way you would interactively.  Newlines flush stream buffers and are, in general, the "go" part of the command.

I cannot find any reference to re-enforce this answer, however.